# Paypal for android how to identify payment item in callback?

Tags: android, flash, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Mobile Payments Library to implement PayPal for Android using Adobe AIR.

When I am creating some PayPalPayment object for user to add an item to buy, how can I get that item in the callback function?

I want to be able to check is the transaction valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to ask, How do I get the item the user added to the cart, inside the callback function?

Comment: yes, when it comes into callback. How do I know what I really get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any additional custom data to identify your payment on your server side trow param:

**payment.setCustomID("some extra not visible data you can pass and it will come back in ipn callback URL to your server");**

```
// Create a basic PayPalPayment.
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

// Sets the currency type for this payment.
payment.setCurrencyType(currency_type);

// Sets the recipient for the payment. This can also be a phone number.
payment.setRecipient(paypal_recipient);

// Sets the amount of the payment, not including tax and shipping amounts.
payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(currency_cost));

// Sets the payment type. This can be PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS, PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, PAYMENT_TYPE_PERSONAL, or PAYMENT_TYPE_NONE.
payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

// Sets the Custom ID. This is any ID that you would like to have associated with the payment.
payment.setCustomID(transaction_id);

// Sets the Instant Payment Notification url. This url will be hit by the PayPal server upon completion of the payment.
payment.setIpnUrl(payment_url_callback);

// Sets the memo. This memo will be part of the notification sent by PayPal to the necessary parties.
payment.setDescription(product_description);
```